# Android Button cause the app crash

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm implementing a settings page which have a radio group and a button to save the choice from radio button. However when I click the save button the app will automatically crash . Please help.

Below is my code

Settings.java

```
        package com.example.sunny.mynote;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * Created by Sunny on 19/04/2015.
 */
public class Settings extends Activity {

    private RadioGroup RadioGroup1;
    private RadioButton rdbRed, rdbBlue, rdbOrange;
    private Button btnSave;
    private EditText textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getApplication()).inflate(R.layout.settings, null);

        RadioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);

        RadioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                if(checkedId == R.id.rdbRed)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Red",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    RadioGroup1.check(R.id.rdbRed);
                }
                else if(checkedId == R.id.rdbBlue)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Blue",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    RadioGroup1.check(R.id.rdbBlue);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "choice: Orange",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    RadioGroup1.check(R.id.rdbOrange);
                }
            }
        });

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEditorActivity.class);
        rdbRed = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbRed);
        rdbBlue = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbBlue);
        rdbOrange = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbOrange);
        textView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.noteText);
        btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Save);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int selectedId = RadioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioGroup1.check(R.id.rdbRed);
                if(selectedId == rdbRed.getId()) {
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                } else if(selectedId == rdbBlue.getId()) {
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0066FF"));
                } else {
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6600"));
                }
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Logcat

```
04-21 22:34:32.357    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-21 22:34:32.357    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:32.377    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:34.257    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-21 22:34:34.277    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:34.327    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:34.327    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:34.357    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:34.367    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:34.907    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:34.907    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onDetachedFromWindow
04-21 22:34:34.907    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:34.917    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 22:34:34.927    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
04-21 22:34:35.237    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-21 22:34:35.237    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:36.897    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-21 22:34:36.897    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:36.907    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:40.757    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:40.787    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:40.787    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:40.797    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:40.817    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:40.867    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:41.357    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:41.357    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onDetachedFromWindow
04-21 22:34:41.357    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:41.367    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 22:34:41.367    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
04-21 22:34:41.637    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-21 22:34:41.637    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:46.297    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-21 22:34:46.297    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:46.317    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:46.337    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:48.257    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:48.257    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 22:34:48.267    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
04-21 22:34:48.547    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-21 22:34:48.547    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:48.987    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-21 22:34:48.987    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:49.007    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:49.007    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:34:51.967    1606-1606/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:05.757    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-21 22:49:05.757    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:05.767    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-21 22:49:05.767    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:05.767    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:05.787    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:05.797    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:07.207    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:08.347    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-21 22:49:08.357    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:08.407    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:08.407    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:08.457    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:08.467    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:08.967    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:08.967    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onDetachedFromWindow
04-21 22:49:08.967    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:08.977    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 22:49:08.977    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
04-21 22:49:09.287    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-21 22:49:09.287    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:10.747    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
04-21 22:49:10.747    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417e0da0)
04-21 22:49:10.757    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sunny.mynote, PID: 8215
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.sunny.mynote.Settings$2.onClick(Settings.java:73)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4630)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19339)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5335)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 22:49:12.687    8215-8215/com.example.sunny.mynote I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 8215 SIG: 9
04-21 22:49:12.877    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote W/ApplicationPackageManager﹕ getCSCPackageItemText()
04-21 22:49:12.877    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote I/PersonaManager﹕ getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-21 22:49:12.917    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
04-21 22:49:12.927    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
04-21 22:49:12.957    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-21 22:49:12.957    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:12.967    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
04-21 22:49:12.967    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:12.977    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:12.997    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:13.017    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:13.027    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 22:49:43.997    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
04-21 23:01:30.597    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
04-21 23:01:30.597    8307-8307/com.example.sunny.mynote D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Comment: post your error log from `Logcat`

Comment: did you mean the eventlog. sorry this is my first day ever touch android studio.

Comment: in which line do you get this error means what do you have in line number 73?

Answer (score 3):

Your `textView` is `null`. Make sure your content view layout `layout/settings.xml` actually has an `EditText` with id `noteText`.

Comment: Oops its actually has to be EditText textview, I already fixed it and yes the EditText id is noteText, but the app still crashed when I hit save button, please check my updates

Comment: no settings does not have any textView. noteText in in another view. I tried to use settings page to change text color in another layout. Please help

Answer (score 0):

use this when you click the radio then call this line

```
 radioGroup.check(R.id.radioButtonman);
  int valuew= radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

valuew is provide Id which radio button are checked.

this line are missing so get the error..

Comment: which part should i put that line , you mean after  textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));?

Comment: your error is    ' int selectedId = RadioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); ' line because no any radio button are checked..

Comment: please check my new update for settings.java. The app is still crash, please help :((

Comment: which part should i put int valuew= radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId(); in?